# Finite sets and convergent subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Claim: If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $F \subseteq X$ is a finite subset of $X$, then any sequence $(a_n)$ in $F$ must have a convergent subsequence.

Hint: Reduce this problem to proving that every sequence must have a constant subsequence.

Lemma: If $(a_n)$ is a convergent sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$ and $(a_{kn})$ is a subsequence, then $(a_{kn})$ is convergent.

Suppose $F$ is finite. Then $F=\emptyset$, or $\exists$ bijection $f:F \to \{1,2,3...,n\}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$. If $F=\emptyset$, then $F$ contains no sequence, and thus the claim is vacuously true. Assume $F \ne \emptyset$.

Let $(a_n) \in F$. Because $F$ is finite, then $(a_n)$ has a finite number of terms, so $(a_n)$ must be convergent. Because $F \subseteq X$, with $(X,d)$ a metric space, then $(a_n) \in F \Rightarrow (a_n) \in (X,d)$. By the lemma, this means that subsequence $(a_{kn})$ is convergent. Therefore, any sequence $(a_n) \in F$ must have a convergent subsequence.

I'm not sure this is correct. My understanding is that a sequence in a subset of a metric space is a sequence in the metric space whose every term is in the subset. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: $\left( a_n \right)$ does not have finite number of terms. But, yes, it has at least one element repeated infinitely. So, just choose that subsequence which will be convergent (since it is constant).

Comment: Think about how your proof applies to $F=\{-1,1\}$ and the sequence $(1,-1,1,-1,\dots)$ from $F$.

Comment: @Aniruddha Deshmukh But why doesn't $(a_n)$ have a finite number of terms if $(a_n) \in F$ with $F$ finite. Where can I find a proof for that?

Comment: @Jamie Radcliffe. Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: By definition, a sequence is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to the given set. So, no sequence can have finite number of terms. In fact, using this definition you can see that the sequence in your case will have at least one term repeated infinitely.

Comment: @Aniruddha Deshmukh no sequence can have a finite number of terms since otherwise the function $a: \mathbb{N} \to F$ wouldn't be well-defined (i.e. not every element of the domain is assigned to something)?

Comment: @Karam Yes, that's right. Though, range of a sequence can have finite number of elements(these elements are also called "terms or elements of the sequence"), but don't confuse these elements with the actual elements belonging to the sequence (a function) which are ordered pairs with every element in N being the first coordinate of some ordered pair. That makes infinitely many ordered pairs and thus infinitely many elements belong to sequence.

Comment: @Aman Kushwaha so since F is finite, then $\exists$ at least one term $a(n) \in a(\mathbb{N})$ that repeats infinitely many times. How would we express this mathematically?